# I can't import keys from Selenium

Tags: selenium, import, pycharm

I got this error:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
ImportError: cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' (C:\PYTHON\p10\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\keys.py).
```

I if I don't write this, it works:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

It opens Chrome and go to the site I want.
I don't know how can I solve the error to can find element and send keys to them.
I think the problem is that I can't import that "keys" and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

you should write import 'Keys' correctly

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

for `send_keys()` method, you don't need import anything.

**The Keys class provide keys in the keyboard like RETURN, F1, ALT etc.**

for more knowing about Keys use this [Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)